# GitHub: How to update the code diff on an open PR?

Tags: git, github

[image: Git branch history]
I created Branches A,B,C. B has all changes of A, C has all changes of B.

I then created PRs for all of them seperately.

PR1 has: Changes of A
PR2 has: Changes of A and B

Then I commited PR1.

What I would expect to happen:
PR2 (and 3) would update their code differences.
--> PR2 has: Changes of only B (and not A anymore)

PR2 still has all changes of A shown in the log - despite these changes already existing on MAIN, there are shown as code differences.

GitHub already allows changes to an open PR by committing to that branch - but apparently does not update the history in cases like this one.

**Is there any like - "update" button to reflect the changes? The shown falsy code differences due to a merge make it harder to review a PR imo**

Comment: PR should be updated automatically. If that doesn't work maybe try changing the target branch to something else and changing back to `main`.

Comment: Did you, by any chance, merge squashing or using rebase or something like that that rewrites history? Then there is a new revision (or many, if rebasing) created for that branch that was merged that is _not_ the same base used by the later branches and so diff won't change.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez This manually triggered an update and did exactly what I wanted. Please change the comment to an answer and I am happy to accept it.

Comment: Note that Pull Requests themselves are not part of Git: any management of a PR is up to the system that provides / hosts the PR (in this case GitHub). (This is not intended as an answer, just a comment to help focus the mind on where to look for the problem and its fix.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PR should be updated automatically. If that doesn't happen try changing the target branch to something else and changing it back to main.